# what is the mistake in this simple sorting array code?

Tags: c, sorting

I'm a new student in the field of coding. I'm trying to understand the concept of array. I wrote a code for sort an array. I will attach my code with this. Please describe what is the mistake on it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
    int a[5]={25,3,4,56,2};
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<5-1;i++){
        for(j=1;j<5;j++){
            if(a[i]>a[j]){
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

The output: 2,25,56,3,4 in this order.

Comment: This is not a sorting algorithm. Tracks what happen by printing swapped values and array content at each iteration, you'll understands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
    for(j=1;j<5;j++){
```

Change it to:

```
    for(j=i+1;j<5;j++){
```

Otherwise it will swap previously sorted elements.  The fixed version starts looking at the first element *after* the one being processed.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe do `for(j=i;j<5-1;j++) if(a[j] > a[j+1])`. Mostly a matter of style I guess.

Comment: @Lundin Either works.  I figure doing an integer addition (by one) is cheaper than doing 2 array loads (of the same value) and a compare, although the addition does add an instruction to the code.